# Claims based authentication - using SPRunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: 2010

If I have web application with Claims Based Authentication, can I use SPRunWithElevatedPrivileges in the code to be deployed on that web application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. This method runs code under web application pool account.